# Bring active call screen to front in Marshmallow Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow, phone-call

Below code is working fine in pre-marshmallow versions (Tested on LG G3) but its not working for Marshmallow (S7 Edge)

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON);
 i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(i);
```

I need to open ongoing call screen if it is minimized.

Comment: please show logcat here

Comment: @HanzalaIqbal there is nothing in logcat to show here ... Above code opens dailer in Marshmallow

Comment: i want to open active call screen

Comment: you want to dial call directly from your App?

Comment: When you minimize the active call screen, android adds a call control view in the drop down notification bar. when we click on that view it opens the active call screen.
I want to achieve this.

Comment: I want to open minimized ongoing call screen

Comment: No, i don't want to call directly from my app

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `i.setFlags` instead of `i.addFlags`

Comment: When you minimize the active call screen, android adds a call control view in the drop down notification bar. when we click on that view it opens the active call screen.
I want to achieve this. I want to open ongoing call screen

Comment: I guess there could be a limitation. But try this